# Trying to fetch all the products that is sold but only one row I get

Tags: mysql

I have this table products

[image]

and carts

[image]

I would like to get all sold products that in cart using this query

```
SELECT products.name,sum(products.price) as price, count(*) as quantity 
FROM carts 
join products on carts.product_id=products.id 
where status = 'sold'
```

But why is it only one row I get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one row is returned because there are aggregate expressions in the SELECT list.

```
  SUM(products.price) 
  COUNT(*)
```

Absent a GROUP BY clause, that is going to cause all of the rows to be "collapsed" into a single row.  Similar to the result we get running

```
 SELECT COUNT(1) FROM foo ;
```

We get a single row back.

---

I suspect you want to add a `GROUP BY products.name` clause to the end of your query.

This will cause all rows with matching value of `products.name` to be collapsed into a single row, but we'll get a row back for each distinct value of `products.name`.